# Innosetup return flag

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I am working on compiling an Inno Setup project. What I am trying to do is check if a folder exists, and if the folder does not exist then I want to uncheck a checkbox in the `[run]` section.

I was trying to accomplish this through the `[Code]` section. However, I cannot figure out how to call the function in the flags of my `[Run]` section.

In my code section, I have the following function that checks to see if the directory exists, if it does not then I attempt to set the flag to be unchecked if the directory does exist I just return any flag.

```pascal
[Code]
function VerifyDir(DirName: String): Flag;
begin
  {Check if directory exists, if it does then set the check flag to unchecked}
  if not DirExists(DirName) then
    Result := unchecked
  end;  
  {Directory Exists return a flag}
  Result := nowait
end;
```

Then in my `[Run]` section, I attempt to pass back the flag from the function like so:

```
[Run]
Filename: C:\3S\LegacyAppFolder\Update.exe; Description: Blah Blah Blah; \
    Flags: VerifyDir('C:\3S\LegacyAppFolder')
```

However, I get an error when I try to compile the installer

> Parameter "Flags" includes an unknown flag.

I assume this is because either I cannot have an inline function and I need to go about this a different way, or this is not possible at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t want to use the `flags` section to do the test.

If you look [here](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptcheck) you will see that the right thing to do is use:

```
Check: xxxxxxx
```

If the check function returns true the statement is processed.